# Activiti BPM: Getting 404 error when I changed my h2 database to mysql

Tags: mysql, activiti

When I change db.properties from webapps\activiti-explorer\WEB-INF\classes\db.properties and restart tomcat, I am not able to open activiti-explorer UI, It giving 404 on browser.

Comment: Can you please share some code details?

Comment: I am not doing coding part, I just change my db.properties and trying to open activiti-explorer on localhost:8080/activiti-explorer from browser.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason may be

- `mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar`
- Database configuration are not proper.

You must provide 'mysql-connector' lib for MySQL database.